# Python: Recognize a part of an Image, and get coordinates

Tags: python, image

I have a problem. I have a screenshot of my screen, and want to recognize a simple button. (I know how the button is looking, and what to find). How to do it? Using PIL? I just want coordinates.

Comment: It's not simple. Look at this site http://www.pyimagesearch.com/

Comment: When you say you know how the button looks, how precisely do you know how it looks? If you know "it's round and red", your code is going to look a lot different than if you know "these are the exact 8-bit RGB colors of each individual pixel of the region, whose exact size is known"

Comment: To be more specific I want to push an Save button of and old IE, but I have to make it to be non-depedend of resulotion.

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot image and button image to ease the understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OpenCV will be a easy answer -- Train an image detector on your button and it will return coordinates. I would suggest a cascade classifier, even though it might be overkill for find a button (Its usually used for face recognition) the library support is very good so it will make your life easy rather then homebrewing something. Resource use is very good also it is designed to run with very little CPU and memory.

http://opencv.org/

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect/table_of_content_objdetect.html#table-of-content-objdetect

Comment: Won't it be an overkill? As I have an image which is contains just the button, and an another which is just a screenshot.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to accomplish -- but if you plan to find that button over and over in lots of different spots itll be 1.) the easiest to code since almost all of the hard work was done in the lib, 2.) the most robust since it can get over lots of things ... cursor over the button? ... button partially obscured ... user has high contrast colors ... user has super high or super low zoom activated ... etc ... etc ... classifier wont care.  3.) Most efficient since that algorithm is well optimized and req's very low resource. It beats anything I could homebrew in a month or so.

Comment: You will need to generate more test data to get the job done. You will eventually need a lot of example to train with, but I assume you can generate that.